# Guarantees on computing $a+x(b-a)$ in floating point

Tags: floating-point

I want to implement the function $f(x,a,b) = a + x(b-a)$ where all the inputs are floating point (doubles, say), such that (a) $f(0,a,b)=a$ exactly; (b) $f(1,a,b)=b$ exactly; (c) $f(x,a,b) \le f(y,a,b)$ whenever $x \le y$; and preferably (d) it is accurate (correct up to rounding) for $0 \le x \le 1$.

Implementing $f(x,a,b)=a+x(b-a)$ directly does not work because for example $f(1.0,-1.0,\operatorname{prev}(1.0)) = 1.0$ (where $\operatorname{prev}(a)$ is the floating point number before $a$). And $f(x,a,b)=b-(1-x)(b-a)$ has the same issue.

Now $$f(x,a,b) = (1-x)(a+x(b-a))+x(b-(1-x)(b-a))$$ has the first two properties.

- Does it have property (c)?
- How accurate is it?
- Is there a more performant way to do this?

Comment: What values can $x$ take? The formula suggests it is used to interpolate between $a$ and $b$, that is, $x$ in $[0,1]$. Is that the case?

Comment: @njuffa Absolutely. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposed alternative
$$f(x,a,b) = \operatorname{ifelse}(x<0.5, a+x(b-a), b-(1-x)(b-a))$$
which also satisfies (a) and (b), but it is not accurate near $0.5$. It also satisfies (c) except maybe at $\operatorname{prev}(0.5)$ and $0.5$.

For example with double-precision arithmetic we compute $f(0.5,-1.0,\operatorname{prev}(1.0))$ to be `-1.11e-16` but it is actually `-5.55e-17`, so out by a factor of 2.

It's worth noting that the implementation proposed in the question gets this example correct.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can exclude cases x ≥ 0.5 as Doris shows: Find an implementation g (x, a, b) which is good for 0 ≤ x ≤ 0.5. If x ≥ 0.5 then 1 - x is calculated exactly without rounding error, so let f (x, a, b) = g (x, a, b) if x ≤ 0.5, and f (x, a, b) = g (1-x, b, a) if x ≥ 0.5.

a + x (b - a) is reasonably accurate if b and a have the same sign. Problem is b, a having different signs (because then there is some x where f (x, a, b) should be very close to zero, and there the smallish absolute error turns into a huge relative error, again as Doris showed - except that will happen for any a, b with different sign for *some* 0 ≤ x ≤ 1).

So assume a, b have opposite sign. Let S = round (b - a), that is the result of floating-point arithmetic. It can be shown that if abs(b) ≥ abs(a) then s = ((S - b) + a) is calculated without rounding error, and therefore b - a = S - s (calculated as real numbers). But if abs(a) ≥ abs(b) then s = ((S + a) - b) is calculated without rounding error, and again b - a = S - s. All this improves the situation, because we can calculate (a + xS) - xs, which is better because we handled the rounding error in b - a.

If you did the calculation in double precision (53 bit mantissa), then you can round both x and S to single precision (24 bit mantissa) and you get two numbers whose predict is exact. Let $x = x_{hi} + x_{lo}$, $S = S_{hi} + S_{lo}$, then $xS = x_{hi}S_{hi} + x_{hi}S_{lo} + x_{lo}S_{hi} + x_{lo}S_{lo}$. The first of the products is calculated exactly without rounding error, and the others are small. So we can calculate a + xS with less rounding error:

$a + xS ≈ (a + x_{hi}S_{hi}) + x_{hi}S_{lo} + x_{lo}S_{hi} + x_{lo}S_{lo}$

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! I didn't get notified so missed it at the time. How do you prove that s is computed exactly?

Comment: If you add or subtract two numbers, the result is always exact if the exponent of the result is not larger than the exponent of either number. Because of that, x - y is always calculated correctly if x/2 ≤ y ≤ 2x.

Answer (score 0):

Linear interpolation is a deceptively simple problem, for which, based on a literature search, no comprehensive nor definitive (i.e. with proven properties and error bounds) treatment seems to have been published to date. My previous attempt to contact a French researcher who has worked on formal proofs for similar "trivial" problems did not yield a response. The following discussion is based on running various arithmetic arrangements with a large number (billions) of test cases. In terms of the basic operations used in such rewrites, one should consider [fused multiply-add (FMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply%E2%80%93add) along with additions and multiplications.

It should be noted that due to the issue of subtractive cancellation, accurate results cannot be achieve when $a$ and $b$ are of opposite sign without the use of some form of extended precision. The initial portion of this answer therefore assumes that $a$ and $b$ have like signs. Likewise it is assumed that none of the intermediate computation leads to underflow, which in my test framework is guaranteed by limiting the range of $a$ and $b$ appropriately. All variants discussed in the following handle the end cases $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ correctly.

```
(1 - x) * (a + x * (b - a)) + x * (b - (1 - x) * (b - a))
```

is the formula suggested in the question above. It is non-monotonic, that is, property (c) does not hold, as simple random test cases show. My tests suggest an error bound of $2.75$ [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) for this formula.

A question on accurate and monotonic linear interpolation very similar to the present one was previously asked on the companion site [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907327/accurate-floating-point-linear-interpolation). The accepted answer there proposes the following arrangement:

```
ifelse (x < 0.5, a + x * (b - a), b - (1 - x) * (b - a))
```

My tests indicate (but *cannot* prove) that this variant is monotonic, including in the vicinity of $0.5$. Error seems to be bounded by $2$ ulps. Personally, I have subsequently adopted a modified form of this, taking advantage of FMA:

```
ifelse (x <= 0.5, fma (b - a, x, a), fma (b - a, x - 1, b))
```

Note the slightly different guard condition. Again, this variant appears to be monotonic according to my tests, and the error bound seems to be $1.5$ ulps. A very fast version for situations where monotonicity doesn't matter is the following:

```
fma (b, x, fma (-a, x, a))
```

This provides an apparent error bound of $1$ ulp, but is easily shown to be non-monotonic via random test cases.

One way of addressing the issue of subtractive cancellation when the signs of $a$ and $b$ differ (which in the worst case leads to results that are off by a factor of $2$ as noted by [Doris](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/105169/doris)), is to perform the intermediate computations in double native precision, using techniques originally developed by Knuth and Dekker.

My own FMA-enhanced attempt at this is shown as C-family code below. Tests indicate it provides monotonicity and an error bound of $0.501$ ulp, that is, results are nearly correctly rounded. It might be more convenient and faster to use built-in higher precision for this approach if available, as in [gnasher729's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/109242/51535).

```c
typedef struct {
    T lo, hi;
} T2;

/* compute x+y, with |x| >= |y| */
T2 add_x_ge_y (T2 x, T2 y)
{
    T2 z;
    T r, s, e;
    r = x.hi + y.hi;
    e = x.hi - r;
    s = ((e + y.hi) + y.lo) + x.lo;
    z.hi = e = r + s;
    z.lo = (r - e) + s;
    return z;
}

T2 aa, ax, bx, tt, rr;
/* -a*x */
ax.hi = -a * x;
ax.lo = fma (-a, x, -ax.hi);
/* b*x */
bx.hi = b * x;
bx.lo = fma (b, x, -bx.hi);
/* a - a*x, Since x <= 1, |a| >= |a*x| */
aa.hi = a;
aa.lo = 0;
tt = add_x_ge_y (aa, ax);
/* a - a*x + b*x */
rr = ifelse (fabs (tt.hi) >= fabs (bx.hi), add_x_ge_y (tt, bx), add_x_ge_y (bx, tt));
return rr.hi + rr.lo;
```